# How to subtract the latest data from any two points in time by using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Given the example documents

```
[
  {
    "_id": "4d54cff54364000000004331",
    "t": "2021-07-10T00:00:01.000Z",
    "data": { "a": 222936, "b": 4824 }
  },
  {
    "_id": "4d54cff54364000000004332",
    "t": "2021-07-10T00:00:02.000Z",
    "data": { "a": 223525, "b": 4863 }
  },
  {
    "_id": "4d54cff54364000000004333",
    "t": "2021-07-10T00:00:03.000Z",
    "data": { "a": 223425, "b": 4892 }
  },
  {
    "_id": "4d54d0074364000000004334",
    "t": "2021-07-10T00:00:04.000Z",
    "data": { "a": 223445, "b": 4905 }
  }
]
```

I need to substract "data.a".
How to use one aggregate command line to process this requirement.
Currently, I use two aggregate command line and calculator in nodejs server.
like this:

```
db.getCollection(`example`).aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            t: {$lte: ISODate("2021-07-10T00:00:04.454Z")},
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {t: -1}
    }, {
        $limit: 1
    }
])
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        '_id': '4d54d0074364000000004334',
        't': '2021-07-10T00:00:04.000Z',
        'data': { 'a': 223445, 'b': 4905 },
    },
];
```

And this one

```
db.getCollection(`example`).aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            t: {$lte: ISODate("2021-07-10T00:00:02.454Z")},
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {t: -1}
    }, {
        $limit: 1
    }
])
```

Result

```
[
    {
        '_id': '4d54cff54364000000004332',
        't': '2021-07-10T00:00:02.000Z',
        'data': { 'a': 223525, 'b': 4863 },
    },
];
```

After run two aggregate I get the document and substract to remainder data.a = 80.
I hope that just use one aggregate to calculate this one.
How to do that?
Thanks!!

Comment: Hi your question is not clear can you please elaborate little bit more thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no "real" way of doing this, the best is to use the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) which just allows you to write multiple pipelines as one, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      t: {
        $lte: ISODate("2021-07-10T00:00:04.454Z")
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      t: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      first: [
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      second: [
        {
          $match: {
            t: {
              $lte: ISODate("2021-07-10T00:00:02.454Z")
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      con: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$first",
          "$second"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$con"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$con"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B_PES3TE6GB)

Comment: Thanks you so much! this also fixed my problem.